# How to check User Availability

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to check the availability of the username when it is going to enter details. Can anybody tell me how I can do it without using hibernate in Java?

```
public static boolean checkUseName (String username) {

    boolean status = false;

    try {
        Connection con = DB.myCon();
        Statement S = con.createStatement();
        String query3 = "select userId from employee where userId ='"+username+"'";

        ResultSet rs = S.executeQuery(query3);
        status = rs.equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Please show some effort

Comment: here is the code what ive tried...but couldnt get the result that i expected

Comment: Since your request ask for a specific `userId` all you have to do is to check whether the result set contains a row. So a single call to [`rs.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) is sufficient. If it returns `true` there was at least one row with that `userId`. But you should learn about using `PreparedStatement`s instead of concatenating SQL `String`s. Otherwise you will become a vitim of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) one day…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the following code:

```
public static boolean checkUseName (String username) {

    boolean status = false;

    try {
        Connection con = DB.myCon();
        Statement S = con.createStatement();
        String query3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee.user WHERE userId ='" +
                username + "'";

        ResultSet rs = S.executeQuery(query3);
        boolean next = rs.next();
        int a = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");

        status = (a == 0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You error is here:

```
rs.equals("")
```

This will always return `false`, because [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is never equal to a `String`. What you want to do is check if the `ResultSet` is empty.

This is not as easy as it seems since there is no `isEmpty()` method, so you'll need to count all rows, like this:

```
String query3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE userId ='"+username+"'";
ResultSet rs = S.executeQuery(query3);
status = (rs.getInt(0) == 0); // Note that rs can be null here
```

This will count all rows from the table `employee` with the given condition (`WHERE userId ='"+username+"'`). Then you can check whether the count is 0.